# How to transpose all four columns under one row and repeat for the rest in four group in an excel?

Tags: sql, excel

I need to rearrange the values in the columns in the each row by only 4 columns after 4 columns matrix.  As shown in Fig1 to Fig2.  Similarly I have do for the values in row 2 of Fig3 and insert between row1 and row2 without deleting the below values.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have tried this `=OFFSET($A$1,,COLUMN()+4*(ROW()-2)-5)`, but some reference error is coming when I am providing `"-5"`.

Kindly help.

With the help of Error's code I got this result

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is VBA. The below code is for one row. modify and try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long, LastColumn As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

        LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        For i = LastColumn To 5 Step -4

            Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

            .Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(1, i - 3)).Select
            .Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(1, i - 3)).Cut .Range("A" & Lastrow + 1)

         Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, so this should be used using VB editor in MS Excel?  Sorry I don't know coding, so asking it.  Is there anything in the code that I have to change in the provded code just to run for 1st row?

Comment: try the code, if there are any issues i m here to help. no changes required.

Comment: at line *With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")*? if yes replace worksheets name (Sheet2) with the name of your sheet!

Comment: Thanks you so much, it worked for one row, however the results are little shuffled.  It did started from 4th column; did not considered the column which has a "space"; due to which all the rows are shuffled.  Also the results shows in latest to the old. (last to start).  Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Yes, I did realised later so I deleted my comment about Sheet name :)

Comment: i m not sure that do you mean. you can may changes to code using debugging. As soon as you find where you should make changes let me know about it and i ll try to help you.

Comment: I have added image to this for better clarity.  Meanwhile will try debugging.

Comment: Please try another time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191445/discussion-between-rupesh-nath-and-error-1004).